# Ayuda para mostrar datos de una DDBB en modal php

Tags: php, mysql, bootstrap

buenas tardes tengo un inconveniente con modal (realmente no comprendo como realizarlo) tengo una BD de libros con 7 campos (id, imagen, titulo, autor, editorial, genero y ubicación) dichos elementos son volcados a una tabla la cual me muestra uno a uno los libros que tengo cargados junto con un Boton "Ver" por cada linea la cual quisiera que lleve a un Modal que tome los mismos valores que tiene puesto en la BD.

y eh aquí la cuestión no tengo idea de como llevar adelante el modal en cuestión.

si me brindan una idea o link de como hacerlo o seguirlo super agradecido!

Codigo de mi table

```
<div class="container">

<!-- Start Table -->

  <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Imagen</th>
        <th>Titulo</th>
        <th>Autor</th>
        <th>Editorial</th>
        <th>Genero</th>
        <th>Ubicacion</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
      <?php

        $sql ="SELECT * FROM libros";
        $resultado = mysqli_query($connections,$sql);

        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado))
        {

       ?>
    <tbody>
      <td><img src="<?php echo $row['5']; ?>" alt=""></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['1']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['7']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['3']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['2']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['6']; ?></td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-warning" >VER</button></td>
    </tbody>
        <?php

          }

         ?>
  </table>

<!-- End Table -->

</div>
```

Comment: Revisa el modal de bootstrap https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp y donde tienes las filas del table coloca <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Editar Registro</button>

Comment: gracias Ger, lo que aun sigo sin comprender es como hacer para que se replique los datos de la tabla en el modal

Comment: ¿Por qué quieres usar un Modal? A mi juicio los modales datan de los años 90 (con el boom de Windows). Hoy día, con Ajax puedes integrar todo en una sola página, tu modal vendría a ser un contenedor de la misma página sin mayores complicaciones y mejor experiencia de usuario.

Comment: buen dia @A.Cedano tienes razón en cuanto al uso del modal, y sinceramente no tenia esa perspectiva del modal =) (me hizo reír mucho tu comentario). Con respecto a Ajax no lo evalué como posibilidad. Buscaré data al respecto, gracias por el aporte!

Comment: Cuando trabajas con un modal, trabajas con dos ventanas (siendo más incómodo para el usuario), la idea es pensar tu interfaz como un solo contenedor (algo así como un escritorio donde tienes varias herramientas, siendo una de ellas los datos que habría en el modal). La clave de todo es Ajax, que te permite modificar parte de tu página de forma dinámica, sin necesidad de recargar. Por ejemplo, si el modal es para presentar datos de empleados, puedes modificar parte de esos datos, borrar uno de ellos, etc y actualizar la información ahí mismo.

Comment: Me parece que hay una confusión de términos aquí entre _modal_ y _popup_ (ventana emergente) y creo que el primer comentario está bien encaminado, solo faltaría ver cómo llenar el contenido.